# Group and display products by category and brand in Django

Tags: python, django, tree

I'm new to Django and I'm currently having troubles creating a very simple list of products, grouped by categories and brands.

Here's the expected result:

```
 - Category 1
    + Brand A
        * Product 1
        * Product 2
    + Brand B
        * Product 3
        * Product 4

- Category 2
    + Brand A
        * Product 5
        * Product 6
    + Brand C
        * Product 7
        * Product 8
```

Here's my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Brand(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand


class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="cat")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_id


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.brand} - {self.name} - {self.category}"
```

My `views.py`

```
def product_list(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    context = {
        'products': products,
        'categories': categories,
        'brands': brands
    }
    return render(request, "product/product-list.html", context)
```

And here's the closest I could get to achieve the expected result in my `product-list.html`

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
    <li>{{ category }}</li>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in brands %}
        <li> {{ brand }}</li>
        <ul>
            {% for product in products %}

            {% if product.category == category and product.brand == brand %}

            <li> {{ product }}</li>

            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

One of the problems is that even if a **brand** has no **product** associated to that **category**, it is still shown and that lead me to think that this is not the best way to do it for sure.

I'd really appreciate if you could point me to the right direction!

Thanks

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

You have a many-to-one relationship from `Product` to `Brand`, you need to add another one for `Brand` to `Category`. Afterwards you can use the related objects reference. Please check this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/